# how to convert UTC date to machine local time zone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I am trying to convert UTC date to machine local time zone (where this function run).I am using `date-fns` library for format. I am getting wrong ouput.

I tried like this

```
const time = "2023-03-07 06:27:06"; //UTC time

const parsedTime = parseISO(time);


const formatInTimeZone = (date, fmt, tz) =>
  format(utcToZonedTime(date, tz), fmt, { timeZone: tz });

const formattedTime = formatInTimeZone(
  parsedTime,
  "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a",
  "UTC"
);
console.log(formattedTime);
```

[image]

I am running this **Mumbai india** so date will come in IST. so 5hour 30min ahead from UTC.

I think epected output should  5hour 30min ahead from given time**.why it is giving in AM**. **it should be in PM**

here is my code.. any suggestion ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-stitch-d8e01m?file=/src/App.js:50-58

Comment: what datetime do you expect to show after executing console.log? give me the exact datetime you want if you use "2023-03-07 06:27:06".

Comment: expect output I think `07-March-2023 11:57AM` .As it is 5hour 30 min ahead

Comment: any idea ?why it is not working

Comment: "2023-03-07 06:27:06" doesn't have an offset so it will be parsed as local. The corresponding UTC date and time will be that date and time minus your offset (or plus your ECMAScript offset). If your offset is +5:30, the corresponding UTC timestamp is "2023-03-07T00:57:06Z". If you parse it as UTC (i.e. "2023-03-07T06:27:06Z") and display as local for you, it will be "2023-03-07T11:57:06+05:30", i.e. 5.30 hours ahead of the initial date and time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second parameter in the function `utcToZonedTime` accepts the resulting timezone as per the [official doc example](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/Time-Zones). So, here if you want to convert into IST format then second parameter should be `IST`.

So,
for `2023-03-07 06:27:06` => IST format will be `07-Mar-2023 11:57 AM`

for `2023-03-07 07:27:06` => IST format will be `07-Mar-2023 12:57 PM`

**Update:**

If you see the ISO format then it also expects the timezone at the end either in the form of Z or +00:00

Eg: `2023-03-07 06:27:06+00:00` OR `2023-03-07 06:27:06.000Z`.

If you write the date in the above format then you will get proper result.
[image: Sample Code]

Comment: I am getting corerct output using `console.log(moment.parseZone(moment("2023-03-07 06:27:06")).local().format("DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a"));
`

Comment: @user5711656—what are you calling "correct"? Date-fns is doing exactly what it should, you misunderstand what the moment code is doing. You're parsing a string with no offset as local into a moment object, then passing that object to *moment.parseZone*, which isn't a valid input (the first argument should be a string, not an object). What happens after that should be explained by someone who understands the innards of moment.js.